# $lub(a, b)$ and $glb(a, b)$ of non- comparable lattice elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, supremum-and-infimum, lattice-orders

In an algebraic lattice $(L, \vee, \wedge, 0, 1)$, the binary operations $\vee$ and $\wedge$ are commutative and associative, satisfying absorption laws. The elements $0$ and $1$ are top and bottom elements, respectively. In other words $0$ is additive identity and $1$ is multiplicative identity.

In general, elements $a,b\in L$ are comparable if $a\leq b$ and in that case, least upper bound ($lub$)of $a$ and $b$= $ a\vee b=b$ and greatest  lower bound ($glb$) of $a$ and $b$=$ a\wedge b=a$

However, if $a$ and $b$ are not comparable, then presumably $lub(a, b)$ =$ a\vee b=1$ and $glb(a, b)$=$ a\wedge b=0$.

> Can we find an example of lattice in which $lub(a, b)$ =$ a\vee b\neq 1$ and $glb(a, b)$=$ a\wedge b\neq 0$ when $a\nleq b$?

Comment: Also, $a\wedge b$ is not usually called the “infimum”; it’s called the greatest lower bound of $a$ and $b$; and $a\vee b$ is the least upper bound of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin you are right. I will  correct it. In your example, $ a$ and $ b$ are not comparable, so getting whole set as the $lub$ and $\emptyset $ as the $glb$, But apparently, whole set is identity elements with respect to set intersection and $\emptyset$ is identity with respect to set union. I am looking for $glb$ and $lub$ to be other than identity elements.

Comment: No, they aren’t “identity elements”. The $0$ element is the *least* element, which in this case is $\varnothing$. The $1$ is the *greatest* element, which in this case is the whole set. The example I gave **is** an example of what you want: the join is not the whole set, the meet is not the empty set. Or else, what you claim you want is not what you *actually* want.

Comment: “lub” by itself doesn’t mean anything. It’s “least upper bound **of** $a$ and $b$”, etc. Just saying “lub” is like saying “give me the name”, and never specifying the name of *what*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your nomenclature is off: $a\wedge b$ is called the greatest lower bound of $a$ and $b$, or the “meet of $a$ and $b$”, not the infimum of $a\wedge b$; $a\vee b$ is called the least upper bound of $a$ and $b$ or the “join of $a$ and $b$”, not the supremum of $a\vee b$. For *complete* lattices, if $S$ is a subset, then $\bigvee S$ is the supremum of $S$, $\bigwedge S$ the infimum of $S$. You could say $a\vee b$ is “the supremum of $a$ and $b$”, but not “the supremum of $a\vee b$”.

Finally, note that “algebraic lattice” is actually a term of art: it means a complete lattice in which every element is a join of compact elements. I think what you mean is “a lattice viewed as an algebra (in the sense of universal algebra)”.

As to the rest, you are somewhat confused. If $a$ and $b$ are comparable, then $a\wedge b = \min\{a,b\}$ and $a\vee b= \max\{a,b\}$. So if, for example, $a\leq b$, then $a\vee b = b$ and $a\wedge b = a$. In particular, if you took $a=0$ and $b=1$, you would have $a\wedge b =0$ and $a\vee b = 1$; your assertion that if they are comparable then $a\wedge b\neq 0$ and $a\vee b\neq 1$ is false.

As to examples: let $L$ be the lattice of subsets of $\{1,2,3,4\}$ ordered by inclusion. Here, $A\wedge B = A\cap B$, $A\vee B = A\cup B$, $\mathbf{0}=\varnothing$, and $\mathbf{1}=\{1,2,3,4\}$.

Let $a=\{1,2\}$, $b=\{2,3\}$. These two elements are incomparable, since neither is contained in the other. Here, $a\wedge b = a\cap b = \{2\}\neq\varnothing$, and $a\vee b = a\cup b = \{1,2,3\}\neq\{1,2,3,4\}$.

In a $01$-lattice, two elements $a$ and $b$ such that $a\wedge b = 0$ and $a\vee b=1$ are said to be “complementary”.

Comment: We can still say that $a \wedge b$ is the infimum of $\{a,b\}$; I'm not sure the OP will get that from your answer and the example with the set $S$.

Comment: @amrsa: But that’s the infimum of $\{a,b\}$, not “infimum of $a\wedge b$”.

Comment: Yes, I understand. I'm just not sure the difference is explicit enough for the OP